# Select all text in a Winforms Infragistics ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics, selectall

Is there a way to do this?  I want to mimic the behavior of a the UltraTextBox.SelectAll method in windows forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to provide the exact version of Infragistics Library...

Does

`this.UltraCombo1.TextBox.SelectAll()`

do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have HideSelection set to true. If you set this to false then textBox1.SelectAll will function as you expect...alternatively you need to give focus to your textbox before calling SelectAll().

I'm not sure how SelectAll works for UltraTextBox but I presume it just selects all the text in the textbox.

Comment: I have a comboBox not a textbox.  I want to do a selectAll on the value in the comboBox--functionally like how the selectAll works on the TextBox.